# Sublime Editor on Apple, Keyboard shortcut equivalent for Windows

Tags: javascript, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

In this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mh5VQVfWTbs

The guy says "Use Command Option Y", and bingo!  It does something.  However, I'm using the Windows version of Sublime, and I have no idea what to do with his keyboard shortcut.

If he'd done it from the menus, I could have followed along.

Can anyone tell me what "Command Option Y" does in the OSx Version of Sublime, and what the equivalent is on the Windows version of Sublime?

Thanks

Comment: Out of the box, it doesn't do anything. He's using a TypeScript plugin and that plugin contains the shortcut, which he mentions, compiles the file. `Ctrl + alt + y` would be the standard Windows equivalent, but you'd need to have the same plugin, he is using, installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that this is a custom shortcut or a shortcut created by some plugin. You can find a list of default keyboard shortcuts in Sublime Text here: 
http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/keyboard_shortcuts_osx.html

The only default keyboard shortcut containing the letter 'Y' is this one:

```
⌘ + Y   Redo, or repeat last keyboard shortcut command
```

From the video it seems like he is basically just running the build process to compile the code to JavaScript. By default this is 'Ctrl + B' in Windows, or '⌘ + B' in OS X.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [unofficial docs](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/keyboard_shortcuts_osx.html)

```
⌘ + Y   Redo, or repeat last keyboard shortcut command
```

the equivalent windows key is

```
Ctrl + Y    Redo, or repeat last keyboard shortcut command
```

in general, Cmd can be replaced with Ctrl for windows, and work.